# I want to code my service worker in HTML file, Can I do this?

Tags: html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Luxsci form builder tool for generating forms and there I can only code Javascript in HTML code (Internal JS). I want to use `serviceWorker` and make it offline with background sync. But its not registering the `serviceWorker` because I don't have `serviceWorker` file for it but adding it in the end of the html code. Also i am adding form link to register it as there is no specific file name. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

[serviceWorker.register](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register) requires a value of `scriptURL`. You will have to have a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: thank you. I am facing the issue on this site because they don't provide a option of separate file.

Comment: It sounds like you'll have to change providers if you want a service worker.

Comment: Yes i got it now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with allowing non file `scriptURL`s is security. As service workers can intercept network requests, a malicious `scriptURL` could prevent the site owner from removing the script, as the URL cannot be changed.

You can see the full discussion [here](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/578).